# How to include jsp file inside another jsp file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, java-ee-6

I am trying to include a jsp file when a button is clicked like so

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#RegisterChildPage').on('click', function() {
            $('.content').html("<%@ include file="FamilyManagerView.jsp"%>");

        });
    });
    </script>
```

My problem is in this line `$('.content').html(<%@ include file="FamilyManagerView.jsp"%>);` There is a syntax error and i don't know what is the correct way to write it.

`<%@ include file="FamilyManagerView.jsp"%>` is not included properly because of the `<% %>`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Add a DIV to your JSP file which includes your other JSP file and it is initially hidden
[image: Hidden div element]

Then remove hidden in onlclick function

[image: onclick function]

`!document.getElementById('testContainer').hidden` - The HTMLElement property hidden is a Boolean which is true and using ! operator you can display the hidden DIV.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Main JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="renderElement()">Render Me</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2" id="testContainer" hidden>
                <!-- Insert your file here -->
                <%@ include file="test.jsp" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
        const renderElement = () => {
            document.getElementById('testContainer').hidden = !document.getElementById('testContainer').hidden;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Or you can use `.load()` which Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements. but you have to give the exact path where your other JSP  is located. As an example - `$("#testContainer").load('../../pages/students/test.jsp');`

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: Please don't add a *new* answer, edit the existing one (or delete the old one).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out @Dave Newton. I have edited my answer.

Comment: No problem--thanks for taking the time to clean things up; it really helps.